# the php extension for mysql

Tags: php, mysql, aix

I just install apache,php and mysql rpm on AIX5.2, but I can't see the mysql information in the phpinfo page,

I would like to know how to made the php extension for mysql that I can call mysql functions in php script.

Thanks

Comment: Better you Install [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html)

Comment: @diEcho I doubt that a generic third-party bundle is easier to install than AIX official binaries.

Comment: @Alvaro XAMPP is easy to install and best server for PHP (AFAIK)

Comment: @diEcho I agree with @Álvaro G. Vicario but another option over XAMPP is to use Zend Server Community Edition (http://www.zend.com/en/products/server-ce/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Linux distributions there's normally a separate package for PHP's MySQL extension, it's likely that AIX follows the same rule. Look for an uninstalled package called "php-mysql" or something similar.

Answer (score 2):

This is more like an OS question. You should check your package manager and find the package wich installs the **php mysql extension**. You probably have your extensions in a different package.

It is also possible that the extension is not enabled. Check your *php.ini* and search for somehing like:

```
extensions=mysql.so
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to ckeck in `php.ini` file is MySQL extesion included. Find `extension=php_mysql.dll`. Try to uncomment it deleting `;` symbol.

Comment: The questions is about AIX, not Windows.

Comment: Ok. What is wrong? `php.ini` exists in UNIX too. And it should be `php_mysql.so` instead of `php_mysql.dll`

Comment: Agree with @Álvaro G. Vicario, but don't think it really merited a down vote! Perhaps the down voter could explain themselves.

Comment: @Treffynnon Certainly, a downvote without explanation is of little help.